# phpMyAdmin showing rows affected = 0

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpMyAdmin 3.3.7 with MySQL 5.1.49 on an Ubuntu 10 LAMP server.

In most situations, phpMyAdmin will show rows affected = 0 when deleting or updating rows, even though rows HAVE been affected. When I try the same query through the MySQL command line, the rows affected is shown correctly. Is there some kind of configuration change I need to make?

Comment: Where does PHPMyAdmin show 'rows affected'?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this was a bug that was fixed in 3.3.10

See the below bug fix reference:
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3153409&group_id=23067&atid=377408

Answer (score 2):

You should try using the most recently released phpMyAdmin